# How do I control tag order in Springdoc OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: java, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

I'm switching from Springfox 3.0 to OpenAPI 3.0 + Springdoc-openapi.
In Springfox the tag order is alphabetical, but in Springdoc's Swagger UI, the order appears to be random.

How do I control the Tag order on the UI?
I'd prefer an ordering of my choosing, but would be OK with ordering alphabetically by tag name.

```java
@Tag(name = MY_CONTROLLER_TAG_NAME, description = MY_CONTROLLER_TAG_DESC)
public class MyController {
```

#### Desired Order:

- Paginated Endpoints
- User Access
- Tagging
- Tagging - Admin
- User Management
- User Management - Admin

#### Actual Order:

- User Access
- Tagging
- Paginated Endpoints
- Tagging - Admin
- User Management - Admin
- User Management

#### POM Dependencies:

```xml
        <springdoc-openapi.version>1.6.4</springdoc-openapi.version>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

#### Application.yml:

```yaml
springdoc:
  show-actuator: ${SWAGGER_ENABLED:true}
  swagger-ui:
    doc-expansion: none
  api-docs:
    enabled: ${SWAGGER_ENABLED:true}
  model-converters:
    pageable-converter:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve something similar using the Quarkus-based rest application? I tried to achieve something similar for my quarkus-based application but could not get anything. Please find my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74627820/7584240

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try either:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter: alpha
```

```
springdoc.writer-with-order-by-keys: true
```

https://springdoc.org/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the order programmatically, you can also try the following (rather crude, but effective) approach:

```java
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public GroupedOpenApi.Builder myAPIBuilder() {
      return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
              .group("My Group")
              .addOpenApiCustomizer(openApi -> {

                  // change order of tags
                  Tag[] reordered = new Tag[10];
                  openApi.getTags().forEach(tg -> {
                      if(tg.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Paginated Endpoints")) reordered[0] = tg;
                      if(tg.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("User Access")) reordered[1] = tg;
                      if(tg.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Tagging")) reordered[2] = tg;
                      // and so on
                  });
                  openApi.tags(Arrays.asList(reordered));
              })
              .pathsToMatch("/api/**");
  }
}
```